# What is the most convenient way to pretty print HTTP responses in the Webkit debugger?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, json, webkit

Firebug's network tab highlights and pretty prints XML and JSON responses, in addition to providing the hard to read raw response body.

On the other hand, Chrome's Webkit inspector will only do syntax highlighting on the XML but will still display it as the single long line that came from the server. I find this to be much harder to inspect then the pretty printed response I get in Firebug or the collapsible tree Chrome's own console.log gives me for XML documents.

**What is the most convenient way to pretty print responses in Chrome's network tab?**

Answer (score 1):

If you handle large JSON response, I'm recommend using JSONView0.0.30 for Chrome. It'll create a full page fully formatted JSON structure.
If XML just use XML Tree for Chrome. It has highlight search function and XSL transform function.